# Lighttpd server can't open jpg images in custom error

Tags: html, web, config, lighttpd

I want to show custom error, while it happens and show some images in that errors, but server don't show it :(
Here is my lighttpd.conf

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
        "mod_proxy",
        "mod_rewrite"
)

server.document-root        = "/home/roman/projects/"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.port                 = 80
server.errorfile-prefix = "/srv/www/htdocs/errors/status-"

mimetype.assign = (
  ".html" => "text/html", 
  ".txt" => "text/plain",
  ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
  ".png" => "image/png" 
)

$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
    url.rewrite-once = ( "^/directory/(.*)$" => "/index.html" )
    proxy.server = ( "" => ( "" => ( "host" => "192.168.1.1", "port" => 80)))
}

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
server.max-request-size = 20480000
```

And my custom 503 error file, which located in `/srv/www/htdocs/errors/`, what should show image from my root directory, but...it doesn't

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ISS_ZDOH</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            background: url(503.jpg) no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100 %;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is error from `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log`:

```
2021-08-11 16:48:55: (mod_proxy.c.523) no proxy-handler found for: / 
2021-08-11 16:48:55: (mod_proxy.c.523) no proxy-handler found for: /503.jpg 
2021-08-11 16:48:55: (mod_proxy.c.523) no proxy-handler found for: /favicon.ico 
2021-08-11 16:49:00: (mod_proxy.c.1417) proxy - re-enabled: 192.168.1.1 80
```

I would be grateful for any help :D

Answer (score 1):

Your full lighttpd config: `lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf -p`.  You only shared part of it.

Similarly, you only shared part of your error log.  The errors you shared suggest that a prior request to the proxy handler failed for some reason, and so lighttpd disabled that backend for a short period of time.  During that time that the bad backend is disabled, there is "no proxy-handler found" that is available to handle the request.

Look at the lighttpd error log and figure out why your proxy backend is throwing errors.